# Вывести ёлочку в консоли

Tags: javascript

Захотелось попробовать вывести [такую же ёлочку как тут](https://ideone.com/ydbkKa) , но с помощью javascript.

Получилось пока так:

```js
var 
  s,
  i,
  size = 10,
  tree = '',
  space = '';

for (s = 0; s< (size/2)-1; s++){
  space += ' ';
}

for(i = 0; i< size/2; i++){
  tree += '* ';
  
  
  if(i == 0){
    tree = '★';
  }
  
  console.log(space+''+tree);
  
  space = space.substring(0, space.length - 1);
}
```

[Код в jsBin в цвете](http://jsbin.com/liyiceh/edit?js,console)

**Вопрос:** Как задать условие вывода символа звездочки `★`, только в самом верху, а не с каждой новой строки? И как можно рандомно добавить на ёлочку еще пару символов в перемешку со звездочками `* **` (символы: `o`, `♥`)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Так получилось :

```js
var
  size = 6,
  space = '';

var items = ['* ', 'o ', '♥ ', '✾ ', '☃ ','☂ ', '❅ ', '❄ ', '✿ '];

for (var s = 0; s < size - 1; s++) {
  space += ' ';
}

for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  if (i == 0)
    console.log(space + '★');
  else {
    var tree = '';
    for (var j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
      tree += items[getRandomInt(0, items.length)];
    }
    console.log(space + tree);
  }

  space = space.substring(0, space.length - 1);
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

UPD: Решил что надо каждую строчку формировать рандомно и отдельно :)